# how to insert multiple records in table in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1

hi there i'm trying to insert data from the cart table to bought table , i should insert multiple records but it only inserts the last value not all , this is my controller function :

```
public function postIndex(Request $request){
 $quantity=$request->input('quantity');
 $total_price=$request->input('total_price');
 $city=$request->input('city');
 $id=$request['product_id'];

 $cart=DB::table('cart')->where('id','=',$id)->value('product_id');
 $x=DB::table('products')->where('id','=',$cart)->value('quantity');

 $user_id=Auth::user()->id;

 if($x < $quantity) {

 return redirect('cart');
}elseif ($x >= $quantity) {

 $data =array(array('quantity' =>$quantity ,'total_price'=>$total_price        ,'city'=>$city,'product_id'=>$cart,'user_id'=>$user_id));

 DB::table('bought')->insert($data);
 $product=DB::table('products')->where('id','=',$cart)->value('quantity');
 $query= $product - $quantity ;
 DB::table('products')->where('id','=',$cart)->update(['quantity'=>$query]);

  return redirect()->action('followController@getIndex');
        }
```

ccan anyone help me knowing what is the error ?

Comment: What's the contents of `$id=$request['product_id'];` ?

Comment: it gets the product_id from the table of products to insert it in the database @apokryfos

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase that. Is `$request['product_id']` a single id or an array of ids?

Comment: no only a single id @apokryfos

Comment: Then your `->insert` would only insert a single row.

Comment: then how can i make it insert a multiple rows ?

Comment: Thoroughly review your logic and update your question with additional clarification and if possible explanation of what each variable is, where its coming from and how you intend to use it. I currently don't see how you can expect to insert multiple rows when you only have a single entry.

Comment: but how can i then get multiple ids from the table to insert them ? @apokryfos